# Linking to CSS in an SVG embedded by an IMG tag

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a page, that includes several SVG files. To synchronize the styling of those SVG files I wanted to create a single stylesheet to hold all styling information.

However, when including the SVG like below, the CSS wont get applied. Anybody having a solution to this or is it just not possible to link to other (CSS) files in an SVG referenced by `<img src="..." />`?

See the example code below. When loading `pic.svg` directly in the browser, all styles get applied and one can see a green rectangle. But when opening `page.htm` all there is to see is a black rectangle. So obviously none of the defined styles was applied.

**page.htm**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <img src="pic.svg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
</body>
</html>
```

**pic.svg**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="styles.css" ?>
<svg version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    >
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" />
</svg>
```

**styles.css**

```css
rect { 
    stroke: black;
    fill: green;
}
```

**EDIT**

From an answer, that for a short time appeared here, I got [this link to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#Scope) and the following citation. In my opinion this states, that the above code should work!

> **Stand-alone SVG document embedded in an HTML or XML document with the ‘img’, ‘object’ (HTML) or ‘image’ (SVG) elements**
>
> [...]
>
> Citing from your link "Style sheets defined anywhere within the referenced SVG document (in style elements or style attributes, or **in external style sheets linked with the style sheet processing instruction**) **apply across the entire SVG document**, but do not affect the referencing document (perhaps HTML or XHTML)."

Answer (score 28):

An alternative is to use the `<object>` tag in your html :-

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="pic.svg" width="100" height="100"></object>
```

It's a BIG shame the `<img>` tag won't work. I don't want to mess about hacking with converting the SVG to a data URI. It's to do with cross-site vulnerabilities on indirectly loading resources and the use of an "Open Redirector".

Note that in my testing lastnight, the `<img>` tag method DOES work in IE10, but neither Chrome nor FireFox.

I don't know why `<object>` is allowed and `<img>` isn't. An oversight?

Comment: No oversight, it's about what people's general expectation is of the capabilities of an image i.e. what you see is what it is every time. The object tag has always allowed for scriptable complex content though.

Comment: I love this answer best, getting a font to show up in my SVG has been driving me nuts all day! Thank you! ... however as you wrote it, it broke the rest of my HTML until I closed it like ` height="100"></object>` needed a closing object tag for some reason: http://scrabblehack.com/

Comment: @RobertLongson "general expectations of an image"... it seems awfully convenient to ignore the countless other ways that images change dynamically.  From a user experience, perception is reality.  An image changing via a hover effect is the same user experience whether we're changing the image source, or if the hover effect is achieved via CSS within the SVG.  Why CSS isn't supported in SVG's outside of object tags is beyond me...

Comment: @RobertLongson I should have been more clear, but was trying to keep it short.  SVG **does** support external style sheets when used in an `object` (at least in Firefox and Chrome; I'm looking it at now), but not within the other applications.  In a perfect/logical world, we'd be able to use an external style sheet with any form of an SVG, not just within an object.  An `img` tag supports animated gifs and even dynamically generated php files (with image headers).  There's no reason it shouldn't support a SVG with an external style sheet.

Comment: @RobertLongson Again, I don't see how we can allow an `img` tag to support a php file... but not allow an SVG to utilize an external css file.  There's no privacy issue with the latter that doesn't already exist by other readily-accessible alternatives.  You can even create an svg in php, which pulls the external CSS in... so the privacy issue seems like a moot concern to me.

Answer (score 14):

For privacy reasons images must be standalone files. You can use CSS if you encode the stylesheet as a data uri. E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8;base64,cmVjdCB7IA0KICAgIHN0cm9rZTogYmxhY2s7DQogICAgZmlsbDogZ3JlZW47DQp9" ?>
<svg version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    >
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" />
</svg>
```

There are various [online converters](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/) for data URIs.

Comment: But in that case I would again have one style definition per SVG file. And how does that relate to the spec extract I posted?

Comment: If you want to share style definitions you can't use image tags. Security issues tend to override specification requirements which generally don't consider such things.

Comment: Apparently, this also means that you can't refer to external fonts from SVG files loaded via an HTML file.

Comment: If the external SVG is referenced from an `<img>` tag then you would need to embed the font data into the SVG file as a data URI. If it isn't included as an image i.e. you use it via `<object>` then you can use external fonts just fine. If you want more details as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are great. I found it simplest, though, to just embed the raw SVG tag itself on my webpage. This allowed the SVG to inherit font-family styles declared in my page's CSS without issue...

Comment: I don't quite understand what "just embed the raw SVG tag itself on my webpage" means - would you mind clarifying?