# How to use external CSS with an external SVG symbol library

Tags: html, css, svg

I am attempting to create a library of SVG symbols for use throughout a website, and to style the symbols using a CSS file.

I can reference a CSS file from within an SVG file just fine. For example, this SVG file (`icons.svg`)

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="aqua-icons.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="my-icon" height="48" width="48" viewbox="0 0 48 48">
      <circle class="filled" cx="24" cy="24" r="24"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#my-icon" x="0" y="0" width="48" height="48"/>
</svg>
```

combined with this CSS file (`aqua-icons.css`)

```
.filled {
  fill: aqua;
  stroke: black;
}
```

displays as an aqua circle in Chrome:

[image: Aqua circle]

(and also Firefox)

The I tried to reference the symbol from another file. (`icons_1.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Storage icons</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="0.5in" height="0.5in" viewbox="0 0 48 48">
    <use xlink:href="icons.svg#my-icon" x="0" y="0" width="48" height="48"/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

The styling disappears. It seems that the stylesheet specification of an external SVG file is ignored in both Chrome and Firefox. As one possible workaround, I added a stylesheet reference to the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Storage icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="aqua-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="0.5in" height="0.5in" viewbox="0 0 48 48">
    <use xlink:href="icons.svg#my-icon" x="0" y="0" width="48" height="48"/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

This brings the aqua styling back in Firefox, but not in Chrome. In this case, it appears that Chrome's behavior is correct according to the standard

> CSS2 selectors cannot be applied to the (conceptually) cloned DOM tree because its contents are not part of the formal document structure.[2](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement)

So is there any way to style externally referenced SVG symbols from an external CSS file?

Comment: I don't think so. [If you want to keep your svg in files, the CSS needs to be defined inside of the svg file.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20720935/2908724)

Answer (score 0):

I have found one potential answer, but I am not sure it is ideal. I run a simple Ajax routine to load the SVG library into the DOM, and then use internal references on my `<use>` elements. Here is what the HTML looks like now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Storage icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="aqua-icons.css">
  <script src="/ext/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#svg-libs").load("icons.svg");
  })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="svg-libs" style="display:none"></div>
  <svg width="0.5in" height="0.5in" viewbox="0 0 48 48">
    <use xlink:href="#my-icon" x="0" y="0" width="48" height="48"/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```