# Can I add ID's to SVG elements in the SVG file the same way as inline code?

Tags: css, svg

I want to manipulate SVG with CSS and I just learned I can add an ID to an SVG element and do this, but putting SVG in the HTML is really messy. My question is, if I load the SVG with an image tag, and add the ID into the SVG file's code, will the ID work the same way?

Comment: Interesting question -- I've only recently started using CSS with inline SVG (via d3.js), and it's a great way to keep color schemes consistent and flexible. I tried a few tests with external files after reading your question, with no success. According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434094/how-to-style-svg-with-external-css), it's probably not possible unless you add CSS to the SVG file itself.

Comment: I did further research and found that this can be done! One must embed the svg via an `object` tag - see this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/ - Ill give someone else an chance to answer with this in case they might already be working on it.

Answer (score 0):

As you may or may not have realised, CSS does not work across document boundaries. So if your SVG is in a separate file, you cannot style it with CSS in your HTML.  Whether it is an `<img>` or an `<object>`.

If you want to style the SVG with CSS, you have two choices:

(1) inline the SVG in the HTML, or

(2) add the CSS stylesheet to the SVG file itself. You can use a `<style>` element, or you can reference an external stylesheet from the SVG:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="my_svg_styles.css" ?>
```

However external references like this will not work if you are embedding the SVG with `<img>` or `background-image`.  There are special privacy rules that forbid it.  All image files referenced from `<img>` have to be self-contained.

Comment: Or (3) inject the CSS at runtime into the SVG using javascript.