# SVG use and IE/Safari iOS

Tags: ios, internet-explorer, svg

I am trying to render a SVG in IE and iOS Safari and for some reason this is not working:

```
<svg aria-label="chevron-down" class="icon form__select-open-icon" aria-hidden="true">
  <use xlink:href="../example/images/icons.svg#chevron-down"></use>
</svg>
```

This works on all other browsers, I can't seem to find the exact reason for this not working properly. IE seems to support this markup.

Comment: What is your test environment? If you are opening this with the `file://` protocol instead of from a real web server, a path to the linked file starting with `../` might violate same origin restrictions.

Comment: @ccprog -- no I am using `../ ` path - I changed the svg to `<svg aria-label="chevron-down" class="icon form__select-open-icon" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" .../></svg>` and worked fine

Comment: @ccprog however I'm using this a lot and would like to use a template for this.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue since the SVG do not display in IE and Chrome.It seem that you've missed view-box.Could you please share your detailed code so that it will be easier to help with you. And maybe you could refer to this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826164/svg-with-use-tag-not-visible