# Can I use svg as button with an effect in the outline of the shape?

Tags: html, css, frontend, pure-css

I'm a beginner and i was just wondering if I can use SVG icons as buttons like make hover for them and active ? and if there is a way to make a border for them but around the shape straight not the box of the shape and fill the shape with a color?
just using pure CSS

Comment: this question will surely help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css]()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style SVG with external CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434094/how-to-style-svg-with-external-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap SVG elements in `anchor` tag or `button` tag to make them behave as a link or button respectively. To add border around the shape you can use the css `stroke` property