# why don't the selectors work on a svg used in my HTML template?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to import an `svg`, which has some paths with class `.desired`,

```
.desired {
 fill: red;
 background: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want to apply the styles on these elements with that class. I don't know why it doesn't work.
If I put the `<svg>` directly in my template it works, but that's what **I want to avoid** since I can have very large .

how can I fix it?

[image]

Expected behaviour

[image]

Note: I want to avoid putting long  directly in the html template.

```js
var desiredElements = document.querySelectorAll('.desired');

desiredElements.forEach(function (element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('"desired"');
  });
});
```

```css
.desired {
  fill: red;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <object
    type="image/svg+xml"
    data="https://svgshare.com/i/xRE.svg"
    class="logo"
  >
  </object>
```

Comment: Why you insert svg through object?

Comment: Related  how to put the style tag in the SVG `<style type="text/css">` https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720935/125981

Comment: You could load the svg via fetch, but be aware of CORS issues here.   If your loading from your own domain that won't be an issue.   When the SVG is loaded say via fetch, just add to your document using `element.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<object>` elements, like `<iframe>`s, load external media in a self-contained document.

The stylesheet belonging to the HTML document does not get transferred through the `<object>` to the SVG.

You'd need to attach the CSS to the SVG itself for it to apply.

(As you observed, if you used an `<svg>` element directly in your HTML document, then the stylesheet would also apply to it).

Answer (score 0):

The svg's cannot be modified if it's in an object element. I know, its frustrating. But there is a way. Try it and thank me later :)

```html
<script>
  // Wait for the SVG to load
  var logoObject = document.getElementById('logoObject');

  logoObject.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // Get the SVG document inside the <object> element
    var svgDoc = logoObject.contentDocument;
    
    // Check if the SVG document is loaded successfully
    if (svgDoc) {
      // Find and style the elements with the "desired" class
      var desiredElements = svgDoc.querySelectorAll('.desired');

      desiredElements.forEach(function (element) {
        element.style.fill = 'red';
        element.style.background = 'red';
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';

        // You can also add event listeners to these elements
        element.addEventListener('click', function () {
          console.log('"desired"');
        });
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```