# Can SVG and Javascript code be kept in seperate files and still have the script manipulate the SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

To keep the code clean I was attempting to put my scripting code in script.js and my SVG code in svg.svg . Additionally I was including these files in my html but the javascript does not run at all. Is there some way to achieve this or do I have to embed the javascript in the SVG code using:

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
 ...
// ]]>
</script>
```

My Current html code includes the javascript and svg in this manner:

```
<embed src="svg.svg" type="svg+xml"></embed>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can include your javascript code directly in the `<script>` tag.  and then your svg code with an `<svg>` tag. I don't quite get what your problem is.

Comment: Your problem seems similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12583879/1169798

Comment: So in my in html file I am including both the svg and js file but for some reason the javascript is unable to change the svg elements. I continued looking and found this:http://apike.ca/prog_svg_jsanim.html but its still not working with that. I feel that I am missing some declaration somewhere.

Comment: is your html served by a http server? or is it loaded via file: protocol?

Comment: Its all client side. I have an html file, javascript file and svg file all in one folder and I am running the html file with references to the js and svg files.

Comment: please post the relevant part of your html code

Comment: I have added it as an edit. It was too cluttered when I put it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I learned a couple of things through my trial and error. Although I am sure most people may already know this I am learning this on my own and it was a big realization for me. For some reason the documentation is not as thorough as one would expect.

1. The markers `<![CDATA[`at the beginning and end `// ]]>` of the script are not really required. The script can be placed out of the svg tags. I believe that in the case that you are placing code within the tags you may need to include those identifiers.
2. The svg file can include the js file in this manner:

   `<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="script.js"></script>`
3. As always the elements in svg can be easily referenced by id. Just give an id and then use `document.getElementById()`
4. Another interesting discovery is that the the O Reily book on SVG located at: http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials
   sometimes uses some old syntax which does not run correctly. So watch out.