# svg @font-face works in svg but not when included in a page

Tags: css, xml, svg, font-face

I've got an svg file which includes a certain font using the `@font-face` syntax. This svg is located at `/logo/logo-big-web.svg` and the font is in `/font/MDN/MDN.ttf` on the server.

Everything works fine when I open `http://www.mywebsite/logo/logo-big-web.svg` in a browser the font loads properly and the svg file is displayed correctly.

However, when I try to embed the svg file in a html file, for instance in `index.html`:

```
<img src="/logo/logo-big-web.svg" ... ></img>
```

When I open `http://www.mywebsite/index.html` in a browser, the font does not load properly and the svg displays an ugly default font.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? How does one get around it?

I know I could embed the font as svg glyphs inside the svg file, but this doesn't work in firefox and adds a lot to the filesize of the svg while I'm loading the font anyways for use on the webpage itself (it seems wasteful to load the font twice). So embedding the glyphs is no option. Same goes for embedded `data:` uri.

### Update:

The font is specified in the svg file as:

```
<defs>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: MDN;
            src: url("/font/MDN/MDN.ttf"); }
    </style>
</defs>
```

and I use it as follows:

```
<text font-family="MDN" font-size="11"> <textPath ... > ... </textPath> </text>
```

### Update 2:

I tried to circumvent the problem by defining the font in a separate stylesheet, and include it like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="/style/slyle.css" ?>
```

But this seems to have the same problem: It works when I open the svg directly in a browser
(`http://www.mywebsite/logo/logo-big-web.svg`) but breaks down when I use the svg in a html `img` tag or as a background to a html element.

Comment: Is the font URI inside the SVG relative? You should see a 404 in your inspector's network tab if that's the case.

Comment: the font uri is specified as: `url("/font/MDN/MDN.ttf")`. Should work if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: You could convert the font into paths in your vector editing software.

Comment: @DJDavid98: Yes, but I'd like to keep that as a final option, plan Z, because it doesn't scale well. I'm going to have a lot of logo's have the same font but slightly different text.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585887/600545), *embedded* svg images have to be standalone images. As mentioned in the comments above, one can make an svg 'standalone' by embedding all external assets into it. So in my case, i'd have to do either one of these things:

1. **embed the fonts using a data uri**: `src: url("data:application/font-woff;base64,<base64 encoded font here")`,
2. **embed the fonts as svg glyphs**, which I had already ruled out because the lack of firefox support
3. **turn the fonts into paths** in my editing software (e.g. *expand path* in adobe illustrator).

Not one of these methods seemed satisfactory, since I really like to keep the svg files as lightweight as possible.

Another solution to circumvene the whole problem is to use a html `object` tag instead of an `img` tag. This way the svg is allowed to be more than a standalone image and it can use the full range of xml inclusion methods to include other assets. [This was pointed out already in the aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399311/600545).

I chose to use the `object`  method of embedding the svg. I'll update this answer if I find out there is something fundamentally wrong with doing this instead of using a proper `img` element.

Comment: Why do you `expand path` and not `join path` in AI?

Comment: @Danger14, probably because my knowledge of AI is sub-par and this is the only thing I know. Do you think `join path` would solve the problem?

Comment: @romeovs this works, but god damnit now my page crash instead.

Comment: A more correct tool would be to use *Create Outlines*, under the *Type* menu. Expand tool seems to do this as well, for type objects, but does much more than that (i.e. it is used to convert any object to pure fills and strokes, or even strokes to fills). Path joining tool is completely wrong tool choice here. It cannot be used to do anything to type objects.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution of using `object`, `iframe` and `embed` tags will fail if the site uses the header `X-Frame-Options:deny`

Comment: If you want to use the 1st solution (embed the fonts using a data uri), I recommend to use the following website: https://transfonter.org (don't forget to toggle on "Base64 encode" option)