# Svg won't use the installed webfont

Tags: css, svg

I'm converting my header to an .svg because it looks horrible scaled down in IE.

There is font in the .svg but I've installed the fonts via dreamweaver and the fonts work fine elsewhere.

Take a look [HERE](http://granthoneymoon.com/temp.html). (you'll have to shrink the browswer to under 800px width to see it) You can see "prayer Pond" written in the body with the correct font, but the header doesn't have the right font. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

You can also note that the OTHER font in the SVG image works just fine and I installed it the exact same way.

Here's the part of the .svg that deals with the font:

```
    <text transform="matrix(0.808 0 0 1 221.228 97.4204)" fill="#B4D1E4" stroke="#B4D1E4" font-family="'ConeriaScript_Slanted'" font-size="83.2657">Prayer</text>


<text transform="matrix(0.808 0 0 1 517.98 96.3726)" fill="#B4D1E4" stroke="#B4D1E4" font-family="'ConeriaScript_Slanted'" font-size="83.2657">Pond</text>
```

And here's the CSS of the text lower down with the same font (that works):

```
.temp {

        font-family: "ConeriaScript_Slanted";

        font-size: xx-large;

        color: #FFF;   

    }
```

Any clue what might be going on here?

Comment: You have a number of files that are not loading correctly. One of them is a stylesheet that refers to ConeriaScript_Slanted. Make sure you have the correct path in your main.css as the 500 error I'm seeing cannot find a file at this location: http://granthoneymoon.com/webfonts/ConeriaScript_Slanted/stylesheet.css

Comment: Sorry about that. Forgot to upload the webfonts to the sample site. It should load now.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is very simple.  The SVG has no idea what font "ConeriaScript_Slanted" is.  If you had inlined the SVG in the page, it would, because it would know about it from the CSS in the HTML.  But the SVG is being loaded as an `<img>` (actually a `background-image`), so all it knows about is what is in the SVG file itself.  CSS does not cross document boundaries.

Unfortunately the fix is not as simple as adding a `@font-face` rule to your SVG.  SVGs embedded via `<img>` must be self-contained.  They cannot refer to external resources (for privacy reasons).  You can still use `@font-face` but the url has to be a data-url.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20587895/1292848

Comment: You've changed the page, so I don't know how it was before, but presumably because it was HTML and not an external SVG.